# Is it possible to pull reviews using a Service Account for a Google My Business Account?

Tags: api, service-accounts, google-my-business-api

Really straightforward question. Is there a way to use the Service Account credentials to gain access to a particular Google My Business location Reviews?

(Some context, I'm not pulling from an unowned business. I have access to the information and we're an authorized user. Essentially we are the business owners or agency)

https://developers.google.com/my-business/

For broader context, we came across this issue:
[How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention)

... and we want to automate the acquisition of reviews for a client who wants to have access to their reviews. However, we need to manually get the refresh token...

Steps 11 and 12 are as such...

> 11. Click Step 2 and "Exchange authorization code for tokens"
> 12. Copy the returned Refresh token and paste it into your app, source code or in to some form of storage from where your app can retrieve it.

We would ideally like to automate this side of the process. Is this feasible using the Service Account and a Restful Endpoint or a library provided by the Nuget Package?

Comment: Hi, how to get an account id and location id?

Comment: Hi @zus, this https://medium.com/swlh/using-google-cloud-platform-and-google-my-business-api-to-obtain-coffee-shop-reviews-8f2e45d322c0 article explains it very well.

Comment: @ShinEmperor, did you already figure it out? I'm running into the same challenge.